# Is it possible to create a full screen HTML popup, like a full screen video player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen

I would like to create a similar experience to a full screen video player, that extends outside of the browser to the full monitor height and width, but with an HTML basis (i.e. I can put in a background and buttons and use CSS to present it to the user).

Is this possible? I'm thinking HTML/CSS/Javascript, but open to any technology.

Comment: This can only be done with `requestFullscreen()`

Comment: That answers my question - if you make it an answer, I can answer it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make something fullscreen using JS you have to use the `requestFullscreen()` method.

From [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_requestfullscreen.asp):

```
/* Get the element you want displayed in fullscreen mode (a video in this example): */
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");

/* When the openFullscreen() function is executed, open the video in fullscreen.
Note that we must include prefixes for different browsers, as they don't support the requestFullscreen property yet */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```